# What is Modio and should I be worried?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, cheats

I'm playing Minecraft over Hamachi with some friends.  One of them said he could make himself op on MY server with a program called Modio.  What is this, should I be worried, and what can I do against it?

Comment: Are you running an "offline mode" server (i.e. `online-mode=false`)?

Comment: @lunboks Yes I am.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what [Modio](http://www.game-tuts.com/community/modio.php) has to do with Minecraft. It seems to be a utility that can transfer game saves between a PC and an Xbox 360.

---

If you are indeed running a server without name verification, you should worry anyway, *if* anyone on your server is an operator. Setting `online-mode` to `false` causes the server not to verify usernames with [minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net/), which allows anyone to log in with any handle they wish. If you have given someone else or yourself operator privileges, this person could hijack the nickname of an op and thus gain their status.

If you want to defend yourself against this, your options are:

1. Enable `online-mode`. Of course, this will effectively ban anyone with a… less *privileged* account.
2. Don't give anyone operator status. Moderate the server directly via the server console.
3. Switch to [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/) and set up local user accounts with a plug-in such as [AuthMe](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/1605/).

Answer (score -2):

Modio is just him saying that to throw you off. In any case, you can op yourself with a network line like that quite easily (port foward, takes 5 seconds and it's self explanatory).